# How after manipulations with two strings get a string in result as well

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Write a method, #present_pet, that takes two arguments:
a pet name and an animal type, both strings. It should return a string
that announces the pet (e.g. if given "Todd" and "turtle", it
should return "Todd the turtle has arrived.").

```
def present_pet(pet_name, animal)
  pet_name.each_line do |pet_name|
    animal.each_line do |animal|
      puts pet_name[pet_name] + " " + "the" + " " \
           + animal[animal] + " " + "has arrived."
    end
  end
end
```

and after I run it, I get just the sentence not converted to a string! how would I make it a string ?

Comment: What do you expect as an input? Why do you `each_line` it?

Comment: Your method does print a string. If you want the double-quotes printed use `p` instead of `puts`.

Answer (score 1):

```
# No need to each line if strings.
def present_pet(pet_name, animal)
    "#{pet_name} the #{animal} has arrived"
end

puts present_pet('Bob', 'builder')
```